# In my /etc/hosts/ file on Linux/OSX, how do I do a wildcard subdomain?

Tags: linux, unix, mac-osx, localhost

I need to test sub-domains on my localhost.  How can I effectively have this result of adding `*.localhost.com` to my `/etc/hosts/` file?

If it's not possible, how do I work around this problem?  I need to test wildcard sub-domains on my localserver.  It is a Django devserver, can the Django dev server handle the sub-domains?  Can some other piece of software/routing give me the end result I want?

Comment: Belongs on superuser ?

Comment: I know people say it's not possible!  But how do I do it anyway!  What is something outside of /etc/hosts/ I can use to get the effect.  I'm testing a development server.

Comment: on superuser: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3352/wildcard-in-etc-hosts-file

Comment: As most answers are focusing on your first question (localhost subdomain wildcards), I'll answer your secondary question as a comment: yes, the Django dev server is perfectly capable of handling localhost subdomains, you just have to convince your browser and your OS to send the traffic its way (using one of the various solutions below)!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I have written a dns proxy in Python. It will read wildcard entries in /etc/hosts. See here: https://github.com/hubdotcom/marlon-tools/blob/master/tools/dnsproxy/dnsproxy.py

Comment: This is perfect! I have been looking for a simple solution like this for a long time (Working on OSX Mavericks BTW)

Comment: now, if we could only just `pip install` it :)

Comment: I installed this, did everything and ran it, but it does not block sites.

Comment: Can not upvote this enough.  I've needed this forever, stumbled upon this gem of a question and answer, and I'm a bit of a Python hacker, and this is a neat tidbit.  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 192):

Install **[dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html)** (I do this on all my Linux desktops as a DNS cache anyways). In `dnsmasq.conf` add the line:

```
address=/localhost.com/127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been wanting this for years. It works wonderfully. Now I don't have to edit /etc/hosts every time I make a new website to test locally.

Comment: dnsmasq.conf didn't exist by default. I created the file /etc/dnsmasq.conf and added just that line and started $sudo dnsmasq. The browsers picked up the changes without restart.

Comment: Brilliant!  Note for Mac users, it really is this simple:  1. `sudo port install dnsmasq` 2. edit `/opt/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf` 3. `sudo port load dnsmasq`

Comment: OSX with brew: same as above but brew install dnsmasq

Comment: fyi brew > port (re @MattHumphrey suggestion)

Comment: This example doesn't work for me, possibly because I'm using http://vagrantup.com for local serving.  Don't worry, I already changed the IP to the correct one `192.168.50.11` but DNS is not resolving.  Any ideas, is this example correct for "non-127.0.0.1" IP's?

Comment: I like how it comes with the rule `/double-click.net/127.0.0.1` commented out... which is exactly why I looked up this question.

Comment: Great tip. For an Ubuntu 14.04 desktop (which runs dnsmasq by default), create a file called `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq-localhost.conf` and put the line `address=/localhost.com/127.0.0.1` in it, then restart.

Comment: For OSX, here is a detail setup http://passingcuriosity.com/2013/dnsmasq-dev-osx/

Comment: Any ideas how to do this or if this still works in Ubuntu 15.10? The instructions above for 14.04 didn't work for me.

Comment: If it doesn't work for OS X check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19651350/1903743

Comment: See https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/08/wildcard-dns-ubuntu-hosts-file-using-dnsmasq/ for more info.  Worked on a Debian 8.

Comment: How can I do this for multiple domains? And how do I refresh after editing the file? I want `*.localhost` and `*.loc`. I added two lines: `address=/localhost/127.0.0.1` and `address=/loc/127.0.0.1`. For some reason only the first one works. And after commenting out both, and calling `sudo service dnsmasq restart` and `sudo service network-manager restart` I still have the *.localhost version working.

Comment: This solution works perfectly. Don't be fooled on Ubuntu 18. There is a dnsmasq.d directory. This doesn't mean dnsmasq is installed! You need to install dnsmasq. Some great instructions can be found here: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-configure-dnsmasq-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

Comment: I followed the instruction from here (https://gist.github.com/ogrrd/5831371) and it worked for me. brew install dnsmasq ;mkdir -pv $(brew --prefix)/etc/;echo 'address=/.test/127.0.0.1' >> $(brew --prefix)/etc/dnsmasq.conf;sudo brew services start dnsmasq;

Comment: adding `nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolv.conf` worked for me for wildcard subdomain.

Answer (score 89):

It is not possible to specify wildcards in the `/etc/hosts` file. Either specify the required hostnames explicitly or alternatively set up a local name server with the appropriate rules.

Answer (score 18):

You need to set up a DNS server and have each *client* use it for resolution. The server itself can be something as "light" as [dnsmasq](http://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2005q3/000361.html) or as heavy as [BIND](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/358).

Comment: +1 for dnsmasq, which is really well-documented and easy to use

Comment: dnsmasq is not able to do this.

Comment: What part of the behavior described in the `--address=` section of the dnsmasq.conf man page doesn't cover the use case describe above?

Answer (score 16):

### Simple Workflow (no need to install anything)

I personally like to create a PAC file for that and make my browser just use it.

**Step 1:** create a file e.g.: `*.proxy.pac*` somewhere (I use my `$home` folder)

**Step 2:** paste this code (example is with port 8000):

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
  if (shExpMatch(host, "*localhost")) {
    return "PROXY localhost:8000";
  }
  return "DIRECT";
}
```

**Step 3**:
Make your Browser use this PAC file.

[Youtube Video for PAC & Firefox](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKB4FoPw15k)

**Step 4**:
Now you can test your app by accessing: `http://mysubdomain.localhost/`

**Step 5:** Enjoy :)

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that this will only affect your browser. Other programs (like `wget`, will not get affected by this). That is not per se a problem, but perhaps it is better to mention this.

Comment: If you go the .pac route and you're implementing a node.js server, you will be surprised to see that `req.url` is now an absolute URL. This is done because the assumption is that you want to write an actual proxy server, but it is surprising if you came to this technique just as a way to stop adding /etc/hosts entries for debugging. FYI to those who might go the same road I did.

Comment: How I can apply this to Google Chrome/mium & Brave browser as well?

Answer (score 6):

I've tidied up an old project of mine:

https://github.com/airtonix/avahi-aliases

requirements:

- linux where avahi and python-avahi are installable
- you're ok with .local domains (avahi doesn't support any other kind)

Advantages over using dnsmasq or the python dns proxy:

- other avahi/bonjour users on your local network can resolve the aliases you create and announce to the network ( providing you're allowing access to port 5353 )

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use a wildcard in `/etc/hosts`.

Have a look [here](http://postpostmodern.com/instructional/a-smarter-mamp/) for a good walkthrough on how to accomplish on OS X using BIND, the built-in but inactive DNS server, and Apache.

Comment: Apache has nothing to do with subdomains.

Answer (score 4):

This DNS based solution worked perfectly in my case, without need to install anything : https://gist.github.com/fedir/04e60d679d5657d1f9f9aa10b3168282 (Mac OSX 10.9)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `dnsmasq` with `NetworkManager` you can (or even must?) start `dnsmasq` from `NetworkManager` by adding

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. Then the dnsmasq config goes to `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.conf` or `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/` resp.

Answer (score 3):

Copying from this blog here is how to do it on mac:

https://hedichaibi.com/how-to-setup-wildcard-dev-domains-with-dnsmasq-on-a-mac/

```
~ brew install dnsmasq

~ vim /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf

# This file will be added to the configuration
conf-file=/Users/your_user_name/.dnsmasq/dnsmasq.conf

~ vim /Users/your_user_name/.dnsmasq/dnsmasq.conf

# example.localhost will be resolved as 127.0.0.1, including subdomains
address=/example.localhost/127.0.0.1
listen-address=127.0.0.1

~ sudo brew services stop dnsmasq

~ sudo brew services start dnsmasq
```

> We need to tell macOS to use 127.0.0.1 as the first DNS resolver.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

Your /etc/hosts/ file won't let you use wildcards or port numbers. You will need to create one entry for each of your subdomain

Comment: What would let you specify port numbers? Not DNS AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you don't. The longer answer is you need to be clearer on what you desire to actually achieve, because there is perhaps either a better way, and a different way to achieve it.

For web-hosting (I've never seen it used otherwise) is done in DNS in combination with a virtual hosting aware web server. For more information on [wildcard DNS records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) (Wikipedia), and an article [Wildcard hosting with Apache and Bind](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/358) for Linux using bind and Apache.

At worst, you could use a local DNS server I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

dnsmasq worked for me, except I had to make some additional steps.

Here is the full procedure:

1. Prepend `/etc/resolv.conf` with the following line

   ```
    nameserver 127.0.0.1
   ```
2. Add the following lines to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

   ```
    listen-address=127.0.0.1
    address=/localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1
    address=/localhost/127.0.0.1
   ```
3. Restart dnsmasq (do not simply tell dnsmasq to reload the config files)

Comment: This will not work if your distro uses netplan (ubuntu 18.04 I'm looking at you)

Comment: That's sad. Just found out netplan was first released in July 2016. I'm sure their way of doing it is "better."

Answer (score 2):

A common task for this subject is to map directories to subdomains. A very straightforward way for that is to append the directory-based entries automatically to the hosts file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

hostsFile = open("/etc/hosts", "a+");

lines = hostsFile.readlines()

for fileName in os.listdir('/opt/subdomainDirs'):

    entryExists = False
    for line in lines:
        if fileName in line:
            entryExists = True  

    if not entryExists:
        hostsFile.write("127.0.0.1 " + fileName + ".localhost\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you tschundeee for what I consider to be the ultimate answer to this issue, wish I could just comment but here is the total configuration for those trying to accomplish the original goal (wildcards all pointing to same codebase -- install nothing, dev environment ie, XAMPP)

## hosts file (add an entry)

file: /etc/hosts (non-windows)

```
127.0.0.1   example.local
```

## httpd.conf configuration (enable vhosts)

file: /XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf

```
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

## httpd-vhosts.conf configuration

file: XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.local
    DocumentRoot "/path_to_XAMPP/htdocs"
    ServerName example.local
    ServerAlias *.example.local
#    SetEnv APP_ENVIRONMENT development
#    ErrorLog "logs/example.local-error_log"
#    CustomLog "logs/example.local-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

restart apache

## create pac file:

save as whatever.pac wherever you want to and then load the file in the browser's network>proxy>auto_configuration settings (reload if you alter this)

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
  if (shExpMatch(host, "*example.local")) {
    return "PROXY example.local";
  }
  return "DIRECT";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be needed.

The `.localhost` suffix should be pointing to 127.0.0.1 in your OS by default.

Currently using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS and it works out of the box without installing any additional packges.

So you can name your test domains as `mytestdomain.localhost` and that'll point to 127.0.0.1. Anything with the `.localhost` suffix will point to 127.0.0.1.

You can try it: `ping helloworld.localhost`, should point to localhost.

```
$ ping test.localhost
PING test.localhost(ip6-localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.023 ms
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
```

This behavior is described in this RFC2606 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2606#section-2

Also described here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html#Synthetic%20Records

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution recently and discovered the [localhost.direct](https://get.localhost.direct) project.

These guys implemented a brilliant idea which works on any OS. **You don't need to install anything.**

SSL certificates are [included](https://github.com/Upinel/localhost.direct#download).

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22.04 with Snaps enabled, [`nss-myhostname`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/nss-myhostname.8.html) appears to be enabled, or there appears to also be an APT package `libnss-myhostname`. Seems you can use any `*.localhost` (or `*.localhost.localdomain`) without any confiuration:

```
$ getent ahosts xxx.yyy.localhost
::1             STREAM xxx.yyy.localhost
::1             DGRAM  
::1             RAW    
127.0.0.1       STREAM 
127.0.0.1       DGRAM  
127.0.0.1       RAW
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind relying on a third-party domain server, there are various easy options (no local OS changes needed). For example `xxx.yyy.127.0.0.1.nip.io` will resolve to `127.0.0.1`. [Docs](https://nip.io/)